# Does every large $\mathbb{R}^4$ embed in $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This question was prompted by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222502/39599).

An exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a smooth manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ with its standard smooth structure. An exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is said to be *small* if it can be embedded in the standard $\mathbb{R}^4$ as an open subset. An exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is not small is called *large*.

> Does every large $\mathbb{R}^4$ embed in $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Freedman and Taylor showed there is a maximal exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, into which all other $\mathbb{R}^4$'s can be smoothly embedded as open subsets. So it would be enough to show that this one embeds in $\mathbb{R}^5$.

By the Whitney Embedding Theorem, every large $\mathbb{R}^4$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^8$, but I suspect one can do better.

Comment: How about this: if $M$ is an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ then $M\times\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$, but since there is a single differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}^5$, it is diffeomorphic to it, and restricting such a diffeomorphism to the submanifold $M\times\{0\}$ gives a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^5$ diffeomorphic to $M$. Did I say something stupid? (I suspect I did, but I can't see it.)

Comment: I guess that is exactly the same argument mentioned by Ian Agol in the comment and a bit generalized result mentioned by Igor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The product of any two smooth open contractible manifolds is diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space, see e.g. remark 5.3 in  [my paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5220); the result is of course not due to me but I don't know any other place where all references are collected.

In particular, this applies to the product of $\mathbb R$ and any exotic $\mathbb R^4$, so the latter embeds into $\mathbb R^5$. In this case the point is that the product is simply-connected at infinity, and hence by a result of Stallings it is PL homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^5$, but any PL structure on $\mathbb R^5$ is induced by a unique smooth structure (as proved by Munkres).

Comment: Wow, that first result is amazing. Thanks!

Comment: What can we say about the end of such embedding?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: I do not know what you mean an "end of an embedding" but I think the diffeomorphism of the product onto $\mathbb R^5$ is fairly explicit. Take a look at Stallings' paper https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/stallings2.pdf.

Comment: This just follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique smooth structure for any $n\neq 4$ from the Stallings paper you reference in your comment. In particular, there is a proper embedding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4